# Eclipse Luna, m2eclipse: empty dependency when dependency is a workspace project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working with Eclipse Luna.

I have a dynamic web project into my workspace: project-web. This project depends on another project into my workspace: project-lib.

So I get this scenario: project-web[:war] ---depends on--> project-lib[:jar]

I have checked "Resolve dependences from workspace projects" option into Properties -> Maven for the web project.

When I run "mvn clean package" for project-web Maven creates war file into the target directory but I have
an issue. If I explode the war file, I find an empty folder called "project-lib" into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Since the library is empty I get some java exceptions on Tomcat startup.

How to create the war for project-web correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Enrico

Comment: Is the project-lib jar empty?

Comment: @6ton - Yes, I hadn't the project-lib.jar under WEB-INF\lib, I get an empty folder named "project-lib".

Comment: If the project-lib jar is empty, then you would get an empty folder. Not sure I understand the issue

Comment: @6ton - the project-lib project into my eclipse workspace is not empty. When I run "mvn clean package" on project-web I get a project-web.war file where the WEB-INF\lib folder contains an empty project-lib folder.

Comment: Run mvn clean install on the project-lib so that the latest version is installed in your local repo and you can use it as a dependency correctly

Comment: @6ton - Yes I know, but this costraint is not right. M2Eclipse should create project-web correctly, I use this plug-in in order to perform this work also.